# In Pandas, how to re-determine the dtypes of columns after dropna?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` constructed via `read_csv`. I want to compute some statistics on a sampled `sub_df`. For `sub_df`, I want to drop all rows with missing NaNs and re-check the true types of the columns.

In my data, many of my integer columns are read as float because of missing values.

Comment: You may want to use `fillna()` to convert `NaN`s to a value of your choice (ie an empty string) instead of dropping them. Otherwise edit your post with some more details.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I just want to `dropna` when computing statistics. `fillna()` is different. And what details do you need?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question. I don't think you can do this automatically, however you can manually convert the datatype of a column using `astype`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan,2,3],columns = ['value'])
df.dtypes
value    float64
dtype: object

sub_df = df[df.value.notnull()]
sub_df.value = sub_df.value.astype(int)
sub_df.dtypes
value    int32
dtype: object
```